# vertically center align <a> tag

Tags: html, css

html

```
<a id='aTag' href='#'> a link </a>
```

css

```
#aTag {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
   text-align: center;
}
```

The `text-align: center` does horizontal-center for a `a` element. How do you vertically center it?

using: `vertical-align: middle` does not work.

Note: Other solutions provided are for multiple divs, not for an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/HQu8Y/

Try to use that:

```
line-height:100px;
```

Comment: The line-height is correct, but the vertical-align will align the anchor to the middle of its siblings, rather than align the text inside of it.

Comment: Yes I know, I didn't want add that line :)

Comment: Note that this technique breaks when your link spans more then one line: http://jsfiddle.net/HQu8Y/2/

Comment: I've updated your [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HQu8Y/1/) to show another option, because yours fails as soon as the text wraps to a second line.